# Equivalence of EPSG:3857 for MapInfo 9.5

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, mapinfo, epsg

I have a raster projected on EPSG:3857 with QGIS. I have image registration in Mapinfo but there is no projection for EPSG:3857.

Do you know the projection that I need to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Popular Mercator was added in MapInfo Professional 9.5.1, so the coordinate system should be there.

We might have used a different EPSG code in v9.5.1. I do recall some fuzz about changing the EPSG code.

Anyway, in the list "Projections of the World" you should find the "Popular Visualization" coordinate system/projection.

That's the one you are looking for.

If it's missing in your projection file, you can open your projection file in a text editor and add these two lines:

```
"Popular Visualization CRS\p3857", 10, 157, 7, 0
"Popular Visualization CRS\p900913", 10, 157, 7, 0
```

We have them twice because people use at least two different EPSG-code for this projection.

If you don't know where to locate your projection file, you can ask MapInfo Pro. Open the MapBasic window, type the statement below and hit Enter on the keyboard:

```
Print "MapInfow.prj: " + LocateFile$(6)
```

I have previously heard about people using the WorkGroup option in MapInfo Professional and in the WorkGroup folder also having a configuration file such as the menu file (MapInfow.mnu) and so not seeing the features added with a new release of MapInfo Professional. Maybe this is what is causing this issue with you!?

### edit 2014-01-07:

Update the 9.5 version to 9.5.1 is needed

Comment: Thanks but "Popular Visualization don't exist!
This is what I have :
"Behrmann Cylindrical Equal-Area WGS84","Eckert IV (Equal-Area) WGS84", "Eckert VI (Equal-Area) WGS84","Gall WGS84",
"Mercator WGS84\p41001", "Miller Cylindrical WGS84", "Mollweide (Equal-Area) WGS84","Robinson WGS84","Sinusoidal (Equal-Area) WGS84\p54008","Behrmann Cylindrical Equal-Area NAD27",
"Eckert IV (Equal-Area) NAD27", 
"Eckert VI (Equal-Area) NAD27",
"Gall NAD27", 
"Mercator NAD27", 
"Miller Cylindrical NAD27", 
"Mollweide (Equal-Area) NAD27",
"Robinson NAD27",
"Sinusoidal (Equal-Area) NAD27"

Comment: Try to add the lines that I have added to the answer above

Comment: Did it work when you added the projections to the projection file?

Comment: Ok, Projection exist in ComboBox but there is an other problem.
The datum 157 isn't supported... It's necessary to custum datum 157 on my system. I think I need declare it in the same file. Do you know the corresponding line for id 157

Comment: I think I need to check this internally. The documentation states that support for "Popular Visualization Datum #57" was added with MI Pro 9.5, but you are right. We are referring to Datum #157. Let me check and get back to you. Maybe it wasn't supported until v10.0 !?

Comment: And you are using MapInfo Professional 9.5, right?

Comment: Yep. I use MapInfo Professional 9.5 . Perhaps it's added with an update... I looked at documentation of v10 and these datum and projection are added on v10 version... Maybe It's possible to add custum projection and custum datum corresponding to it.

Comment: I was told that it was added in MapInfo Pro 9.5.1. Unfortunately I have not been able to find that patch. It's not on the web site anymore.

Comment: Ok, there is no solution at the moment for me, so I need to use another more recent version. Thanks